# I do not need support for older browser then IE11 do I need modernizr?

Tags: html, css, modernizr, html5boilerplate

I have came to know about H5BP and modernizr. now I have developed website which is made in flexbox and I do not want support for older browser then IE11. (coz I do not care for IE 6 to 10).

now I have seen that modernizr detects browser support and tells to add "no-XYZ" class to make it work for older browsers. but I do not want to do that hard work to make it work in IE6 to IE10. should I remove modernizr ? from H5BP ?

I'm already using HTML5SHIV.

Answer (score 1):

Modernizr isn't about letting you use other browsers, it is about letting you know wether or not a feature is enabled in the users current browser. As you add features to your website, check their compatibility on caniuse.com. If it is not stellar support, consider using Modernizr for fallbacks.

Answer (score -1):

```
HTM5 and CSS3 are the latest versions and have advanced features which are not supported by the older browser engines. To detect these features in browser we will use modernizr library.

Ex : 

    if (Modernizr.canvas) {
        alert("This browser supports HTML5 canvas!");
      } else{
        alert("This browser does not supports HTML5 canvas!");
    }
```